# Angular 9 http.delete returning Unsupported Media 415

Tags: c#, angular

have read a little bit of answers on google and they all point to the old way of posting using previous versions of angular. How can I make this work for angular 9? currently sending this from my typescript file

> ```
> this.deletingUser.UserId = deleteUser.userId;
> this.deletingUser.ShopId = deleteUser.shopId;
> this.deletingUser.AccessType = 0;
>
> this.http.delete(environment.apiUrl + 'UserAccess/', this.deletingUser).subscribe(response => {
>       console.log(response);
>     }, error => {
>       console.log(error);
>     });
> ```

Error

```
status: 415 title: "Unsupported Media Type"
traceId: "|5c70708d-40084eb40ba86edc."
type: "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13"
```

No problems with Get/Post/Put using the exact same format

Comment: Anything from fiddler/logs to see what type is being posted?

Comment: Can you post the code from your controller endpoint signature ?
Are you using from body or query ?

415 usually indicates wrong method ( GET, POST and so ... )

Comment: it's strictly the .delete that is causing this issue if i replace it with .get, .post or .put the request works fine